# What is the best architecture we can use for a Netty Client Application?

Tags: multithreading, netty

I need to develop a netty based Client, that accepts messages from a Notification Server, and places these messages as Http Requests to another Server in real time. 
I have already coded a working application which does this, but I need to add multi-threading to this.
At this point, I am getting confused on how to handle Netty Channels inside a multi-threaded program, as I am all loaded with the conventional approach of sockets and threads.

When I tried to separate the Netty requesting part into a method, It complains about the Channels not being closed.
Can anyone guide me how to handle this?
I would like to use ExecutionHandler and OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor, but I am really new into this.

Help with some examples would be a real favour at this time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the example code on the [Netty site](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation)?  The [TelnetServer](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/telnet/TelnetServer.html) looks to do what you are talking about.  The factory creates new handlers whenever it gets a connection.  Threads from the `Executors` will be used whenever there is a new connection.  You could use any thread pool and executor there I suspect:

```
// Configure the server.
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
        new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),       << change
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));     << change

// Configure the pipeline factory.
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new TelnetServerPipelineFactory());

// Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
```

The [TelnetServerHandler](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/telnet/TelnetServerHandler.html) then handles the individual results.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {

    // Cast to a String first.
    // We know it is a String because we put some codec in TelnetPipelineFactory.
    String request = (String) e.getMessage();

    // Generate and write a response.
    String response;
    boolean close = false;
    if (request.length() == 0) {
        response = "Please type something.\r\n";
```

When the telnet is ready to close the connection it does this:

```
ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(response);
if (close) {
    future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Thats not correct. If you use nio you share the threads. So no new thread per connection

Comment: The `ServerBootstrap` class takes a pair of thread pools and yet connections share threads?  Are you sure @Norman?  That seems illogical.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.. I'm one of the core-devs of netty ;) The given Executors are used to obtain the needed threads (boss and worker threads). By default the number of worker threads are 2 * cpu-count.

Comment: Oh, I think we agree @Norman.  The threads out of the pool are used.  I did not mean that a new thread was created with each connection.  I've tweaked my answer to better reflect that.  Of course with the `newCachedThreadPool` it would create a new thread, but only if necessary.  Thanks for Netty!!

Comment: ah ok... so it seems like I missunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an ExecutionHandler to the ChannelPipeline. This will make sure that every ChannelUpstreamHandler which is added behind the ExecutionHandler will get executed in an extra thread and so does not block the worker-thread.